# Where in PCA does the non-uniqueness of eigenvectors come from?

Tags: linear-algebra, data-analysis, invariance, principal-component-analysis

I tried comparing [sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html) with a linear kernel to [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) on the same data set and got different eigenvectors. My understanding is that these should be equivalent methods, which I thought should entail that the eigenvectors would be equal.

But it is mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/208099/69508) that "*in PCA it doesn't matter where the eigenvectors point as long as lines created by those vectors have proper directions.*"

I take this to mean that there should be some sort of transformational invariance. It would help my understanding to see where in [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) this invariance, or at least non-uniqueness, shows up in PCA.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the eigenvectors are normalized to have unit length,  the non-uniqueness comes from needing to pick a basis for each **eigenspace**.

For example, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$. All the vectors $x$ for which $Ax = \lambda x$ forms a linear subspace, lets call that subspace $E$. The dimension of that subspace is the same as the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

The issue is that there is a degree of freedom when choosing the **basis** of the subspace $E$. The choice of basis being the set of orthogonal vectors $x_1,...,x_d$ such that $\text{span}(x_1,...,x_d) = E$. Any choice of basis is going to be a valid set of eigenvectors, but numerically the actual basis a method provides you depends on the method used to find the eigenvectors, and if that method uses a random initialization then the actual basis you get will also be random.

As a concrete example, for the identity matrix you can choose **any** set of orthogonal vectors to get a basis for the eigenspace.

Comment: Orthogonality of the basis elements for one eigenspace isn't even technically required, even though it is desirable and achievable. And you still have non-uniqueness even when eigenvalues are distinct and eigenvectors are normalized due to the ability to flip the sign (or in the complex case to change the phase).

Comment: Every point made by @Ian is exactly correct. These are all possible sources of non-uniqueness